# org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, apache-axis, soapui

I am trying to forward ArrayList as the parameter from .Net environment to the webservice file generated by Axis2. But it's displaying the type as follows in the WSDL file

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="myMethod" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Also, if I test the WSDL file using the soapPUI, it's displaying the following message in the Form **"Type : [{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType] is not supported by the Form Editor"**

And if I manually  forward the details in the XML file then it's displaying the following error message :  **org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String**

What am I supposed to do to fix this issue ?

Comment: Can you post full details of the exception? Including the message of the inner exception and the stack trace?

Comment: The type System.Object[] may not be used in this context.

Comment: StackTrace "   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write1_Object(String n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write2_myMethod(Object[] p)" String

Comment: ex {System.InvalidOperationException} System.Exception

Comment: You should edit your question with that, not post comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing an array list but rather an array of objects, and I don't believe such an array is serializable:

```
 Dim resultString As String = MyService.myMethod(myAL.toArray)
```

What type is the myMethod argument?

Comment: My method argument is ArrayList<String> in Java

Comment: eventhough if I forward arraylist(myAL) am still experiencing the same error message